# Restoring `System.keychain` from a Time Machine backup without access to system `/var/db/SystemKey`

Tags: macos, time-machine, keychain, encryption

I have an old backup that (hopefully) holds the encryption keys to some encrypted disks in the `System.keychain`. To unlock that properly, [I seem to need the `/var/db/SystemKey`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/307189/how-to-decrypt-the-system-keychain-from-another-mac-at-the-command-line) that does not seem to be present in the backup.

I've been searcing around and can't seem to find any solutions that *don't* need the `SystemKey` file (which makes sense if it is the encryption key), but since that computer has since been wiped and given on, I can't imagine any way of restoring it (though if it can somehow be deterministically created on the specific computer, I could ask the new user to create the key if I knew how)

If I can't recover the `SystemKey`, what other options are there? Are the keys in my `System.keychain` gone for good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately for all practical purposes the keys are gone for good.

You need the `SystemKey` file corresponding to that `System.keychain` in order to restore anything from it. If you haven't got a backup, you'll have to resort to bruteforcing the contents of the `SystemKey` file - which is not practically possible.

Comment: lyk dis if u cry evrtime :'(

Comment: I was kind of hoping for an answer like "Hey it's saved elsewhere in the backup" or "No worries, the new user can just use these commands to recreate the `SystemKey`". Goshdarnit. Thanks!